# How to merge two dataframes and get the resulting dataframe be indexed properly (starting from zero up to the number of rows-1)

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 2 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2
2 3 1 1 1
3 3 1 1 1
4 3 1 1 1
5 3 1 1 1
```

df2:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 9 9 9 9
1 9 9 9 9
2 9 9 9 9
3 9 9 9 9
4 9 9 9 9
```

I'd like to get this as their combination:

```
   0 1 2 3
0  2 2 2 2
1  2 2 2 2
2  3 1 1 1
3  3 1 1 1
4  3 1 1 1
5  3 1 1 1
6  9 9 9 9
7  9 9 9 9
8  9 9 9 9
9  9 9 9 9
10 9 9 9 9
```

I have tried `df = df1.append(df2)` but i get this as the result:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 2 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2
2 3 1 1 1
3 3 1 1 1
4 3 1 1 1
5 3 1 1 1
0 9 9 9 9
1 9 9 9 9
2 9 9 9 9
3 9 9 9 9
4 9 9 9 9
```

How can I get the version I want?

Comment: you need `df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your sample data frames correctly, you need to basically concat both frames ?

try

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
    0   1   2   3
0   2   2   2   2
1   2   2   2   2
2   3   1   1   1
3   3   1   1   1
4   3   1   1   1
5   3   1   1   1
6   9   9   9   9
7   9   9   9   9
8   9   9   9   9
9   9   9   9   9
10  9   9   9   9
```

if regards to your own code, you are close but you need to add the `ignore_index` clause which will create a new index for you

```
df = df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
print(df)
    0   1   2   3
0   2   2   2   2
1   2   2   2   2
2   3   1   1   1
3   3   1   1   1
4   3   1   1   1
5   3   1   1   1
6   9   9   9   9
7   9   9   9   9
8   9   9   9   9
9   9   9   9   9
10  9   9   9   9
```